# GetView вызывается несколько раз

Tags: android, listview

Я описал наследованный от ArrayAdapter адаптер для ListView, однако метод getView, вызывается 12 раз вместо 4х. Единственное решение которое было найдено - установка в layout_width и layout_height параметра match_parent, однако это не помогло. Как еще можно исключить повторные вызовы getView?

Код адаптера

```
public ExecuteAdapter(
        int resId, ArrayList textPack, ArrayList imagePack,
        int mainLayout, Data summaryPack, int summaryLayout, Data summaryCommandPack){
    super(GlobalActivity.getActivity(), resId, new String[textPack.size()]);
    this.textPack = textPack;
    this.imagePack = imagePack;
    this.mainLayout = mainLayout;
    this.summaryLayout = summaryLayout;
    this.summaryPack = summaryPack;
    this.summaryCommandPack = summaryCommandPack;
    new LogExt("list size - "+textPack.size());
}

public View getView (int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    currentView = inflater.inflate(mainLayout, parent, false);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) currentView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
    loadText(pos);
    loadImage(pos);
    createSummaryField(pos);
    new LogExt("call getView");
    return currentView;
}
```

Вывод в лог

```
05-20 23:15:45.981    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ list size - 4
05-20 23:15:45.981    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ end load
05-20 23:15:46.011    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.021    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.061    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.071    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.141    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.151    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.161    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.171    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.221    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.251    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.261    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.271    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.301    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.311    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.321    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.351    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.361    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.371    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.371    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
05-20 23:15:46.381    1433-1433/com.example.s D/fileComp﹕ call getView
```

Comment: Да, ViewHolder помог, спасибо.

Comment: да тут не только ViewHolder нужен, а и дополнительное условие, что View уже создан, что собственно описано в любом нормальном руководстве.


А в целом getView может дергаться достаточно часто и это личное дело ListView. Не нужно закладываться на то, что getView будет дергаться какое-то кол-во раз или в каком-то определенном порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для того что бы при каждом появлении нового элемента списка заново его не пересоздавать используйте ViewHolder в адаптере